# Illustrator cc file in ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any way to open adobe illustrator cc files in ubuntu? I have tried with inkskep and it does not work for adobe CC ai files. What can be done? Is there any online converter for free?

Answer (score 12):

A non exhaustive list, based on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Illustrator_Artwork) and the Software Centre:

- [**Ghostscript**](http://ghostscript.com) - converts AI postscript files into other formats. Provides libraries for other pragrammes, e.g. GIMP, to import AI files. Available from the Software Centre.
- [**Inkscape**](http://inkscape.org) - imports old Postscript-based AI files (up to AI version 8) and AI files based on PDF (AI 9.0 and above). Available from the Software Centre.
- [**Skencil**](http://www.skencil.org) - alternative vector editor for Linux supporting AI.
- [**sK1**](https://sk1project.net/sk1/) - supports PostScript-based AI files up to AI version 9.
- [**UniConvertor**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uniconvertor/) - supports PostScript-based AI files; available from the Software Centre.
- [**Xara Xtreme**](http://xaraxtreme.org/) - commercial software that runs on Linux.
- [**XnView**](http://xnview.com) - said to open AI files saved with the PDF compatibility option.
- [**Zamzar**](http://zamzar.com) - online tool that converts AI files into other image formats, GIF, JPG, PNG, etc.

Comment: The Xara Xtreme does not appear to be active any longer. The last updates are from 2009.

Comment: Zamzar worked, didn't even have to install anything.